# Dynamic create table and panel based on database asp.net

Tags: dynamic, html-table, label, panel

I want to dynamic create table and panel based on my database. So now I having a problem. How do I create the table and panel which include 1 linkbutton and label dynamically?
Here is the html tag which I want to create:

```
<asp:Panel CssClass="rightColumnModule2ContentSub" runat="server">
    <asp:Panel CssClass="rightColumnModule2TitleSub" runat="server">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text=" Inventory Report"></asp:Label> 
    </asp:Panel>
    <table class="table100">
        <tr>
            <td class="tableVT" style="width: 49%">
                &nbsp;<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Module/Report/reportPreview.aspx">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
            </td>
            <td class="gapHori1" style="width: 2%">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Panel>
```